# Специализация шаблонного члена за пределами класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

К примеру имеется класс с шаблонной функцией членом `get` которая никак не специализируется в хидере этого класса. В другом файле (`cpp`, за пределами объявления этого класса) я создаю две специализации этого шаблона, которые будут юзаться далее в коде. Так вот, после компиляции я получаю весьма странный результат: в дебажной версии (оптимизация `-O0`) при вызове шаблонных членов я вызываю именно специализированные функции, а в релизной (оптимизация `-O3`) вызываются "пустые"...

Почему?

Вот пример:

структура:

```
.
├── build.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── TemplateClass.hpp
└── utils.cpp
```

код:

```
# cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(template)

include(build.cmake)

set(PROJECT_SRC
  main.cpp
  utils.cpp
  )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRC})

# build.cmake

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

if(NOT DEFINED BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL Debug)
  enable_testing()
  include(CTest)
endif()


if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -g -O0")
endif()

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib")


option(leak_check "set leak_check" 0)
option(profiling "set profiling" 0)
option(thread_check "set thread_check" 0)

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL Debug AND leak_check)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer")
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL Debug AND thread_check)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=thread")
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL Debug AND profiling)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -pg")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -pg")
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -pg")
  set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -pg")
endif()


if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
  set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
endif()


message(STATUS "buid type        " ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
message(STATUS "Project          " ${PROJECT_NAME})
message(STATUS "c compiler       " ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
message(STATUS "cxx compiler     " ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
message(STATUS "build tests      " ${BUILD_TESTING})
message(STATUS "build shared     " ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS})
message(STATUS "leak   sanitizer " ${leak_check})
message(STATUS "thread sanitizer " ${thread_check})
message(STATUS "profiling        " ${profiling})
```

```
// main.cpp

#include "TemplateClass.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;

  TemplateClass a{"string", 0.5};

  std::cout << "first: " <<  a.get<std::string>() << std::endl;;
  std::cout << "second: " <<  a.get<double>() << std::endl;;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
// TemplateClass.hpp

#pragma once

#include <string>

class TemplateClass {
public:
  template <typename T>
  T get() const {
    return T{};
  }

  std::string string_;
  double      double_;
};
```

```
// utils.cpp

#include "TemplateClass.hpp"

template<>
double TemplateClass::get<double>() const {
  return double_;
}

template<>
std::string TemplateClass::get<std::string>() const {
  return string_;
}
```

PS имхо, мне не нравится специализация шаблонов за пределами объявления класса, но вынужден это использовать (имеется ввиду: специализацию без ее объявления, как в примере)

Comment: почему вам не нравится специализация за пределами обьявления класса, если она нужна?  Это эквивалентно как сказать, что: "мне не нравится писать  классы, но вынужден"

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я имел ввиду вышеописанный пример, где специализация не объявлена. Так что не используйте эту фразу вне контекста

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы *определения* специализаций размещались именно в отдельном `.cpp` файле - пожалуйста. Однако при этом все специализации членов должны быть предварительно *объявлены* в заголовочном файле

```
// TemplateClass.hpp

class TemplateClass {
  ...
  template <typename T> T get() const { ... }
  ...
};

template<> double TemplateClass::get<double>() const;
template<> std::string TemplateClass::get<std::string>() const;
```

Без этого поведение не определено.

---

Логика, скрывающаяся за этим требования языка, проста:

В отсутствие предварительных объявлений при компиляции `main.cpp` компилятор просто *не знает* о том, что где-то в каком-то `utils.cpp` существуют специализированные версии этих функций. В оптимизированном коде при компиляции `main.cpp` компилятор просто спокойно, ни о чем не подозревая, генерирует "пустые" версии этих методов на основе шаблона класса и *встраивает* их код прямо в точку вызова.

В неоптимизированной версии при компиляции `main.cpp` встраивания не происходит, а генерируется честный вызов для последующего разрешения на этапе линковки. Так как в традиционной реализации специализированные версии являются обычными ("сильными") символами, а версии, сгенерированные из шаблона, являются "слабыми" символами, линкер подхватывает именно ваши специализации и в неоптимизированной версии все как будто "работает". Но это не более чем побочное совпадение.

---

Однако такие тривиальные специализации имело бы смысл целиком поместить в заголовочный файл, объявив их `inline`.

Comment: Спасибо, только последнее - лишнее, они такие тривиальные потому что это пример