# Шаблонная функция с разным типом возвращаемого значения

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Итак есть класс, разбит на два файла:

Test.h

```
#pragma once

struct Test
{
    template<typename T>
    static T foo();
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

template<>
int Test::foo()
{
    return 42;
}

template<>
std::string Test::foo()
{
    return "43";
}
```

Использование:

```
#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::foo<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Test::foo<std::string>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
42
43
```

Можно ли избавиться от явных спецификаций в .срр файле и написать одну функцию, которая бы возвращала разные типы данных в зависимости от типа шаблона?

Типа так:

```
template<typename T>
T Test::foo()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    {
        return T{ 42 };
    }
    else
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        return T{ "43" };
    }
}
```

Comment: в дополнение к ответам хочу заметить, что не стоит писать определение шаблонной функции в `cpp` файле - это [потенциальная проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001482/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0), особенно если будете использовать ваш хидер в нескольких `cpp`.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, это было сделано специально, чтобы код не собирался при использовании неизвестных спецификаций шаблона, в новом варианте будет static_assert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю, в чем проблема... Вот, в VC++ 2017 спокойно работает - как в inline-варианте, так и в вынесенном:

```
struct Test
{
    template<typename T>
        static T foo()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        {
            return T{ 42 };
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
        {
            return T{ "43" };
        }
        else return T{};
    }
};


struct West
{
    template<typename T>
    static T foo();
};


template<typename T>
T West::foo()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    {
        return T{ 42 };
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        return T{ "43" };
    }
    else return T{};
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::foo<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << West::foo<std::string>() << std::endl;
}
```

А если в том, что вы хотите в .cpp добавить реализацию шаблонной функции - ну, тут или вам надо все равно указывать явное инстанцирование для используемых в другом .cpp-типов, т.е. писать в Test.cpp

```
template  int Test::foo<int>();
template  string Test::foo<string>();
```

либо не хотеть странного и не выносить реализацию шаблонных вещей в .cpp-файлы...

Comment: спасибо, я что-то заглючил, из-за неправильных ключей компилятора у меня не собиралось

Comment: может стоит удалить вопрос, т.к. ошибка не связана с сутью вопроса?

Answer (score 3):

можно, https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zk6xRL

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

 struct test {
     template<class T>
     static auto foo() {
         if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
            return T{ 42 };
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
            return T{ "43" };
        }
     }
 };
int main() {
  std::cout << test::foo<int>() << test::foo<std::string>() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, я что-то заглючил, из-за неправильных ключей компилятора у меня не собиралось